# Add a jar file into confluent connect CRD type

Tags: kubernetes, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use JDBC Connector from a Confluent platform running in kubernetes AKS cluster.
I can create the connector but i face this error:

```
 No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://maria-db-mariadb.mariadb.svc.cluster.local:3306/iotdata
```

I know that is because I don't have the driver installed into the connector folder but i don't know how to inserti it in the right position.

this is how i create the Kafka Connect:

```
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect
  namespace: ckafka
spec:
  replicas: 1
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.3.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.5.0
  configOverrides:
    server:
      - config.storage.replication.factor=1
      - offset.storage.replication.factor=1
      - status.storage.replication.factor=1
  build:
    type: onDemand                                             
    onDemand:
      plugins:
        locationType: confluentHub                             
        confluentHub:                                          
          - name: kafka-connect-jdbc                                         
            owner: confluentinc                               
            version: 10.6.3
```

I have a Statefulset named connect and the relative pod, connect-0.

Can someone give me a step-by-step to follow for insert mariadb jdbc driver please? I am pretty new to kubernetes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.3.0` with your own image, containing the plugins **and JDBC drivers** you want, as documented here

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/docker/development.html#create-a-docker-image-containing-c-hub-connectors

And get a jar from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

---

The plugin may have downloaded correctly, but Mysql/MariaDB JDBC driver has a software license that makes it so Confluent will not include it automatically.